# .net core some content in response returned from controller has been changed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, soapui

I have some data being returned from http client sendasync method similar to below:

```
using (var response = await Client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
{
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    var message = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = message,
        ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString(),
        StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode
    };
}
```

the content in the message that i am getting back contains characters such as

> "xœ½�Y�·€ßØÿÐOÁL€m5Ùì+0èrà
> ¶eK‰ä<ŒW#k�Ý•¢9°}X<º9MV±†š‚FÇ«ªy|,’ÅÞêÑ‹ê‹/}óôëgUóå—Õ“gO«'¯./}%*©ªWo//DÕè_¢mWOcÕOCÝ÷Õ«»Ë‹¦–íT5u34½þ£k‡êã/Éÿþáo—¯7/>¾ÿ°m7ïvúó¶Ú^µ›Ç‡ÃîúÝÝþþðP=Ûv7·Û+¹yØþ»zõ÷Ë‹çÚðÆ» †¾*táõ¦
> d«çß<­ªà‘DðH^É
> ëF?Z?hQ%ÿ¹¼èûzìµœk)+ÙŽõ4T¢¯›±ú¸¿¼øñÏÕ½ŒIgŒ[Ö×³Pus\ÕÞÅNÔ­²U]AÅV®¡æÞoÕæƒþ
>
> > ìLµ™ýVÿ{w·�6ûð¡¾¿¼ø|·Ä0Ôã„¹µ2÷ýR“mÓ×­8¡&Û¥&Yeq—[!j5h—ÛZö9—O3'+!W¶ºZµ˜­gŸîî¶WÝæ·­h6Õãí4Ÿn/óq{£[íz·í7‡›÷ð÷ðq^÷””fðüU¡&QwLSß'Æ­rÀÓ½¶µã½ª[Í5ÚpâíŸ9_›>o¾vOq$Ð6]=¶Aù¦k [¨ŠNuµÃ4�§JøÇ°Õm¾Z*;ôs"

however when my controller returns this the content has changed and instead now looks like:

> xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Oï¿½Lï¿½m5ï¿½ï¿½+0ï¿½rï¿½
> ï¿½eKï¿½ï¿½<ï¿½W#kï¿½Ý•ï¿½9ï¿½}X<ï¿½9MVï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½y|,ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ñ‹ï¿½/}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½gUï¿½ï¿½Õ“gOï¿½'ï¿½./}%*ï¿½ï¿½Wo//Dï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½mWOcï¿½OCï¿½ï¿½Õ«ï¿½Ë‹ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½T5u34ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½oï¿½ï¿½7/>ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½m7ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½Ç‡ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½P=ï¿½v7ï¿½ï¿½+ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zï¿½ï¿½Ë‹ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Æ»ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½*tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
> dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½<ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½H^ï¿½ ï¿½F?Z?

The code in the controller is similar to:

```
public async Task<ContentResult> MyAction()
{
    string request = await ReadRequestBody();
    ContentResult result = await _service.Post(request);
    return result;
}
```

When stepping through the code i can see that the correct value is in the content result.
Has anybody seen this before and know how to fix this issue so that the content is returned unchanged.

Comment: What ContentType is being set? Is it `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: the content type being set is text/xml

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<c6bd78ff48e84725b1f750b32daafc68>"; boundary="------=_Part_20200731012614.895762"

Comment: Ah, so it's XML that contains those characters?

Comment: yes the content that is in the message variable is xml content

Comment: Is the XML still formatted well?

Comment: Is that XML tagged as containing utf-8? check first lines of the XML if there's anything related to UTF-8. If not, then maybe your current xml-formatter writes that as some other encoding that doesn't handle those characters, hence conversion error, hence '?'.

Comment: yes the resf of the xml is formatted well

Comment: in startup.cs i have services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); so i am not changing anything with xml encoding

Comment: Where are you seeing the bad data? How are you testing that? I assume your using F12 dev tools in a browser? Check the `Content-Type` response header. Does it differ than the `ContentResult`'s ContentType in your controller?

Comment: I'm seeing the bad data using soapui. The two content types match up.

Comment: @mxmissile we are seeing the correct content type `multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<6ffad062f7ef4b8c840bc023128e10axx>"; boundary="------=_Part_20200803080412.304356"`. The content that comes out is different to what is in the `ContentResult` when using SOAP UI. The reason we are using SOAP UI is because of the ability to extract the attachments

Comment: I added that the soapui tag to hopefully get this more exposure.

Comment: Looking further into this today I suspect its not a SOAP UI issue, hitting the API with another application and writing the returned bytes to pdf they are still blank, and there are additional characters in place. It appears the return object has more characters in place when it is being returned from the API. Prior to it being written to the content object of the ContentResult all the files write to disk perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string requestBody, string action)
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ""))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

and then in your controller return it like this

```
var result = await _service.Post(requestBody, action);

var stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
await stream.CopyToAsync(HttpContext.Response.Body);
```